# Node.js and Jade, rendering a jade file on button click

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a page with buttons on it, and with each button press, I want to render a different jade file. Simple example:

test.js

```
/*
 * Module dependencies
 */
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render('myBlock', {})
});
app.listen(3000);
```

test.jade

```
!!! 5
html
    head
        title Block Testing
    body
        button(onclick='changeBlock()')
            Random Block
        block content
```

myBlock.jade

```
extends myBlock
block content
    p Hello World
```

How would I implement the 'changeBlock()' function to do this? or what should I do instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you'll need to port Jade to the client-side, i.E. with browserify and compile Jade during runtime. But that's a lot more work ...

To keep it simple, hard-code everything in JavaScript in the changeBlock handler.